# Combining module files in Python

Tags: python, packaging

Is there a way to put together Python files, akin to JAR in Java? I need a way of packaging set of Python classes and functions, but unlike a standard module, I'd like it to be in one file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at Python Eggs: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs

Or, you can use regular zips: http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html

Comment: Thank you! I had seen the term 'egg' used, but I had no clue what it was.

Answer (score 10):

After looking for a solution to the same problem, I ended up writing a simple tool which combines multiple .py files into one: [PyBreeder](http://pagekite.net/wiki/Floss/PyBreeder/)

It will only work with pure-Python modules and may require some trial-and-error to get the order of modules right, but it is quite handy whenever you want to deploy a script with some dependencies as a single .py.  Comments/patches/critique are very welcome!

Comment: I did [something similar](https://github.com/thomasballinger/pyconcat) because it seemed cool, but PyBreeder looks less ridiculous and hacky.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to just use `zip`. A `jar` file in Java is a zipfile containing some metadata such as a manifest; but you don't necessarily need the metatada -- Python can import from inside a zipfile as long as you place that zipfile on sys.path, just as you would do for any directory. In the zipfile you can have the sources (.py files), but then Python will have to compile them on the fly each time a process first imports them; or you can have the bytecode files (.pyc or .pyo) but then you're limited to a specific release of Python and to either absence (for .pyc) or presence (for .pyo) of flag -O (or -OO).

As other answers indicated, there are formats such as `.egg` that enrich the zipfile with metatada in Python as well, like Java `.jar`, but whether in a particular use case that gives you extra value wrt a plain zipfile is a decision for you to make

Answer (score 1):

You can create zip files containing Python code and import from zip files using [zipimport](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html). A system such as [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (cross-platform) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (Windows) will do all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/) for informations.
Also, [Import modules from Zip](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html).

Answer (score 0):

[stickytape](https://pypi.org/project/stickytape/) (mentioned [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764751/240463)) worked for me.

```
stickytape importingSomeModules.py > resultWithEmbeddedImports.py
```

Sometimes you just want to redistribute just a single `.py` file, so neither *PyInstaller*, *zipimport* nor *Python Eggs* cut the deal then.

*PyBreeder* is (currently) throwing exceptions.