# How to build a single python file from multiple scripts?

Tags: python

I have a simple python script, which imports various other modules I've written (and so on).  Due to my environment, my PYTHONPATH is quite long.  I'm also using Python 2.4.

What I need to do is somehow package up my script and all the dependencies that aren't part of the standard python, so that I can email a single file to another system where I want to execute it.  I know the target version of python is the same, but it's on linux where I'm on Windows.  Otherwise I'd just use py2exe.

Ideally I'd like to send a .py file that somehow embeds all the required modules, but I'd settle for automatically building a zip I can just unzip, with the required modules all in a single directory.

I've had a look at various packaging solutions, but I can't seem to find a suitable way of doing this.  Have I missed something?

[edit] I appear to be quite unclear in what I'm after.  I'm basically looking for something like py2exe that will produce a single file (or 2 files) from a given python script, automatically including all the imported modules.

For example, if I have the following two files:

```
[\foo\module.py]
def example():
    print "Hello"

[\bar\program.py]
import module
module.example()
```

And I run:

```
cd \bar
set PYTHONPATH=\foo
program.py
```

Then it will work.  What I want is to be able to say:

```
magic program.py
```

and end up with a single file, or possibly a file and a zip, that I can then copy to linux and run.  I don't want to be installing my modules on the target linux system.

Comment: I think that you are after a [package](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) (this is what Drahkar is describing in his answer). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155914/how-to-create-a-python-2-x-package-simple-case) question and the excellent accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packing Python files into a single .py script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368040/packing-python-files-into-a-single-py-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution involving modulefinder, the compiler, and the zip function that works well.  Unfortunately I can't paste a working program here as it's intermingled with other irrelevant code, but here are some snippets:

```
zipfile = ZipFile(os.path.join(dest_dir, zip_name), 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED)
sys.path.insert(0, '.')
finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script(source_name)

for name, mod in finder.modules.iteritems():
    filename = mod.__file__
    if filename is None:
        continue
    if "python" in filename.lower():
        continue

    subprocess.call('"%s" -OO -m py_compile "%s"' % (python_exe, filename))

    zipfile.write(filename, dest_path)
```

Answer (score 65):

I found this useful:

http://blog.ablepear.com/2012/10/bundling-python-files-into-stand-alone.html

In short, you can .zip your modules and include a `__main__.py` file inside, which will enable you to run it like so:

```
python3 app.zip
```

Since my app is small I made a link from my main script to `__main__.py`.

*Addendum:*

You can also make the zip self-executable on UNIX-like systems by adding a single line at the top of the file. This may be important for scripts using Python3.

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python3' | cat - app.zip > app
chmod a+x app
```

Which can now be executed without specifying python

```
./app
```

Comment: Also works for our legacy 2.7 scripts. Wow! It's a shame this isn't more widely known.

Comment: I just tried this with Python 3.11. Excellent!

Answer (score 17):

Use [stickytape](https://github.com/mwilliamson/stickytape) module

```
stickytape scripts/blah --add-python-path . > /tmp/blah-standalone
```

This will result with a functioning script, but not necessarily human-readable.

Comment: I expected a readable concatination of my Python scripts, but for me it generated unreadable code full of special stickytape calls.

Comment: @CGFoX thanks for catching that, I updated the response text to reflect that to save time for people who look for human-readable output.

Answer (score 12):

You can try converting the script into an executable file.
First, use:

`pip install pyinstaller`

After installation type ( Be sure you are in your file of interest directory):

`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed filename.py`

This will create an executable version of your script containing all the necessary modules. You can then transfer (copy and paste) this executable to the PC or machine you want to run your script.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You should create an egg file. This is an archive of python files.

See this question for guidance: [How to create Python egg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026395/how-to-create-python-egg-file)

Update: Consider wheels in 2019

Comment: Don't I need a package for that?

Comment: @xorsyst: (1) Your development setup should be completely separate from your deployment setup, so you are in fact free to organise your code how you like (2) Once you have your egg it is one file. If you can put two files somewhere, you can put one file there (3) You seem to be aggressively discounting workable solutions by throwing up new requirements. This is impolite to say the least.

Comment: 1: My development setup is separate from my deployment setup.  It's my development setup that is restricted. 2: I have no problems with having an egg. 3: I'm not throwing up new requirements, just clarifying the original badly-worded ones

Comment: @xorsyst: You can't create directories in your development environment? Complain that that is preventing you from working effectively.

Comment: I can create directories to store temporary copies of files, what I cannot do is a fullscale reorganization of our codebase just to make this particular task easier.

Comment: @xorsyst: I'm not suggesting a fullscale reorganisation of your codebase. However, it sounds like there might be an issue with your code organisation if you need to deploy related files stored in wholly unrelated places.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to send a single .py is if the code from all of the various modules were moved into the single script and they your'd have to redo everything to reference the new locations.

A better way of doing it would be to move the modules in question into subdirectories under the same directory as your command. You can then make sure that the subdirectory containing the module has a `__init__.py` that imports the primary module file. At that point you can then reference things through it.

**For example:**

App Directory: `/test`

Module Directory: `/test/hello`

`/test/hello/__init__.py` contents:

```
import sayhello
```

`/test/hello/sayhello.py` contents:

```
def print_hello():
    print 'hello!'
```

`/test/test.py` contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import hello

hello.sayhello.print_hello()
```

If you run `/test/test.py` you will see that it runs the print_hello function from the module directory under the existing directory, no changes to your `PYTHONPATH` required.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving source files around is not possible.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Now you are contradicting your previous statement in the question at the top. You stated that you wanted to move everything into a single directory/file. If you are unable to move any of the modules in question then you can't even do what it is you are asking due to your own internal policy, all technical limitations aside.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I can't permanently move files around on my system.  What I want to do is collect all the necessary source files into a single file that I can put on the target system to run the python.  I don't want to install the libraries there.  Basically, I'm looking for py2exe, but that produces a source-based archive that is cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to package your script with all its dependencies into a single file (it won't be a .py file) you should look into [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  This is a tool that lets you build a sandbox environment to install Python packages into, and manages all the PATH, PYTHONPATH, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH issues to make sure that the sandbox is completely self-contained.

If you start with a virgin Python with no additional libraries installed, then `easy_install` your dependencies into the virtual environment, you will end up with a built project in the virtualenv that requires only Python to run.

The sandbox is a directory tree, not a single file, but for distribution you can tar/zip it. I have never tried distributing the env so there may be path dependencies, I'm not sure.

You may need to, instead, distribute a build script that builds out a virtual environment on the target machine.  [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.0.0a1) is a tool that helps automate that process, sort of like a "make install" that is tightly integrated with the Python package system and PyPI.

Comment: You should use `pip` with virtualenv instead of `easy_install`.

Comment: Interesting module - but I don't think I can use it to create an environment on Windows and then port it to Linux

Comment: No, definitely not.  You might be able to make a buildout script that automatically creates and populates a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken into considerations [Automatic script creation](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) of distribute the official packaging solution.

What you do is [create a setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create%20setup.py&submit=search) for you program and provide entry points that will be turned into executables that you will be able run. This way you don't have to change your source layout while still having the possibility to easily distribute and run you program.

You will find an example on a real app of this system in [gunicorn's setup.py](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/setup.py)

Comment: Sounds interesting, but when I tried the example given it didn't work.  Could you provide an example of how to use this?

Comment: @xorsyst I added an example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this, but it didn't seem to work.  It built a zip containing everything in my current directory, and didn't include my imported modules.  Am I using it wrong?

Comment: I think I did not understand you question sorry.