# How to "#include" a file in python like in C (Copy-paste text substitution)?

Tags: python, import, include, preprocessor

Say I have a file `x.py` and another file `y.py`.
In a C program , the preprocessor would simply copy the contents of `x` and replace `#include x.py` with them, and similarly with `y`.

Python does not preprocess like that - there is no `#include`; `import` works very differently from simple text substitution/replacement, which is what I want (the end result should be one single file that has everything, but it isn't practical to work with such a file during development).

What I'm currently using is essentially something like : `cat globals.py functions.py main.py > final.py`

Comment: *import works very differently* - What do you mean by this ?

Comment: @Ram I simply mean that `import != include`.

Comment: I think this really boils down to some fundamental differences between the two languages. C is compiled and the purpose of said preprocessing step is to facilitate compilation. Python on the other hand is an interpreted language and the import statement brings a module that was previously out of scope into scope. There isn't a reason to combine everything into a single file in Python AFAIK but I believe you could just cat the files together in a pinch. People discussed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163345/how-to-combine-and-get-a-single-python-file-by-resolving-the-imports).